# How to use "ListenForWebhook" in go-telegram-bot-api with gin?

Tags: go, telegram

if i use the following construction, everything is OK. But this construction uses tgbotapi.Update - it doesn't really work for me. I want to use tgbotapi.UpdatesChannel via function tgbotapi.ListenForWebhook().

```
import (
"github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
tgbotapi "github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5"
)
type TelegramBot struct {
    API   *tgbotapi.BotAPI 
    Upd   tgbotapi.Update
    UpdCh tgbotapi.UpdatesChannel 
    Log   *logger.Logger
}
func (tlg *TelegramBot) InitTg(cfg *config.Config) {

    bot, err := tgapi.NewBot(cfg.Telegram.Token)
    if err != nil {
        tlg.Log.Fatal(err)
    }

    tlg.API = bot
    router := gin.Default()
    if cfg.TelegramMode != "webhook" {
        botUpdate := tgbotapi.NewUpdate(0) 
        botUpdate.Timeout = 60
        tlg.UpdCh = tlg.API.GetUpdatesChan(botUpdate)
        go tlg.Start()
    } else {
        router.POST(cfg.Telegram.Path+"*any", tlg.WebhookHandler)

    }
    go router.Run(cfg.Listen.BindIP + ":" + cfg.Listen.Port)
    //TODO fix me :)
    for {

    }
}
func (tlg *TelegramBot) WebhookHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    defer c.Request.Body.Close()

    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
    if err != nil {
        tlg.Log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, &tlg.Upd)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    go tlg.Start()
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": "not you :)"})

}
func (tlg *TelegramBot) Start() {
    //TODO: for webhook
    if tlg.Upd.Message != nil {
        chatID := tlg.Upd.Message.Chat.ID

        tlg.analyzeUpdate(chatID)
    } else if tlg.Upd.CallbackQuery != nil {
        chatID := tlg.Upd.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.ID

        tlg.analyzeUpdate(chatID)
    }

    //TODO: for polling
    for update := range tlg.UpdCh {
        if update.Message != nil {
            tlg.Upd = update
            chatID := tlg.Upd.Message.Chat.ID

            tlg.analyzeUpdate(chatID)
        } else if update.CallbackQuery != nil {
            tlg.Upd = update
            chatID := update.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.ID

            tlg.analyzeUpdate(chatID)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this, if possible (to get the webhook data into the tgbotapi.UpdatesChannel as in polling) :

```
router.POST(cfg.Telegram.Path+"*any", func(c *gin.Context) {
 tlg.UpdCh = bot.ListenForWebhook(cfg.Listen.BindIP + ":" + cfg.Listen.Port + cfg.Telegram.Path +     bot.Token)
 go tlg.Start()
 c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": "not you :)"})
})
```